# On Dremio, how do i add a blank/pseudo column in Select statement?

Tags: sql, dbeaver, dremio

I'd like to know how to add a pseudo column in select statement using Dremio?

on MS SQL, I am able to simply use below statement to add a blank column on my result.

```
SELECT ' ' as [Pseudo_Colum] 
FROM  Table
```

How am I doing it on Dremio?

Comment: What is the error you get? I don't know Dremio, but standard SQL uses double quotes for identifiers, not those dreaded square brackets. Did you try `select ' ' as "Pseudo_Column" from ...`

Comment: ah...you were right, I just changed brackets to double quotes and that works  
thank you so much :)